# Next.js - On Shallow routing for dynamic path it is removing the basePath from browser url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

i have a dynamic routes:
Pages
- [name]
- [brandid]

the browser url should base `[basePath]/[name]/[brandid]`. After doing shallow routing
`router.push("?page=2", undefined, { shallow: true });`

the url removes the basePath. And only shows `/[name]/[brandid]`

Comment: `router.push` will automatically add the `basePath` setup in the config. Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

When you have dynamic routing in Next.js, and want to do a shallow adjustment of the route to reflect updated query params, you probably want to do something like this:

```
const router = useRouter()
const url = {
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, page: 2 }
    }
router.push(url, undefined, { shallow: true })
```

This will retreive the current path (`router.pathname`) and query (`router.query`) details, and merge them in along with your new `page` query param. If your forget to merge in the existing query params you might see an error like:

> The provided href value is missing query values to be interpolated
> properly